# Callback invocation in Android when Google Assistant starts listening

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, google-assistant-sdk, android-audiomanager, google-assist-api

One of the functionality in my Android app is it starts playing media received from Backend server. It uses `MediaPlayer` callbacks and functions to handle playing, stopping and pausing the Audio speak by the app. It also use `AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener` to handle focus changes. I am getting a callback of `AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT` when Google Assistant starts to listen and speak. I am able to control the app media stop based on this callback. In other case when Google assistant is already speaking I am not able to get any callback ?
What things can be used to check already Google assistant is speaking/listening so that I can skip playing my app audio

I tried overriding inside MainActivity

```
 override fun onProvideAssistContent(outContent: AssistContent?) {
        super.onProvideAssistContent(outContent)
        navigationMediaPlayer.stop()
    }
```

This basically is called when the user is requesting an assist, to provide references to content related to the current activity. But didn't worked. Still the sound is getting overlapped.
How this can be resolved ?